# Find security group based on name

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-security-group

I'm trying to add a Security Group to a lambda starting from it's name. Since they are automatically generated by our pipelines based off the stack name, the ID's and names are the same. I want to attach the SG named "Db-Sec-Group123456" to my lambda.

Since the 123456 part is randomly generated and changes from time to time, I want to make this dinamic. Is there a way for me to list the Security Groups with a name **like** the one I want (but not the exact same)?

I tried this but it can't find the desired group when deploying:

```
const DbSecGroup = SecurityGroup.fromLookupByName(this, 'Db-Sec-Group', 'Db-Sec-Group', vpc);
```

The only similar example I can think of is the `LIKE` statement in SQL, but I'm new to CDK and programming so I can't really find a good example.

Thank you in advance for any help!

**Alternative solution**

Since I wanted the security group to be able to connect to our database through a lambda function, and due to our project structure, I created a new security group on our DB stack and exported it to the stack I needed, allowing me to connect to the BD. It worked something like this:

Database Stack:

```
this.exportValue(lambdaSG.securityGroupId.toString(), { name: '${environmentWithUpperCase}LSGid' });
```

Lambda Stack:

```
const lambdaSGId = Fn.importValue(`${environmentWithUpperCase}LSGid`);

const lambdaSG = SecurityGroup.fromSecurityGroupId(
      this,
      lambdaSGId,
      lambdaSGId,
    );
```

Comment: in case the security group is generated as part of a cloudformation stack you can exports it's id for example as an exported cfn Output, then use `Fn.importValue` ([ts api docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.Fn.html#static-importwbrvaluesharedvaluetoimport), [cf docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html)) to get the id which can then be used to do lookupById - https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/import-value-aws-cdk-cross-stack for an example using this with a bucket name

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I actually did something similar, but with `this.exportValue`. It worked something like this: 
    this.exportValue(lambdaSG.securityGroupId.toString(), { name: '${environmentWithUpperCase}LSGid' });

Comment: Imported like this: 
    const lambdaSGId = Fn.importValue('${environmentWithUpperCase}LSGid');

Answer (score 0):

If you are not creating security group from CDK then there are multiple options  to do it.

If your security group is already created then you can keep the unique id based on stage(dev,qa, prod) in secret manager or parameter store.

Refer https://kuchbhilearning.blogspot.com/2022/10/get-security-group-from-id-aws-cdk.html

If you want to specifically fetch using name then you can do the same, but security group name has to be exactly the same.

https://kuchbhilearning.blogspot.com/2022/10/find-security-group-based-on-name-aws.html

Comment: Thank you for answering! I wanted the security group to be able to connect to our database through a lambda function. Due to our project structure, and since the names have a random string attached, I created a new security group on our DB stack and exported it to the stack I needed, allowing me to connect to the BD. Thank you for the explanation anyways, It's a good ideia to keep it in SM and I'll keep it in mind going forward :)